# Question about an identity related to Poisson distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> Prove that if $W$ is Poisson($\lambda$), then $E(\lambda g(W+1)-Wg(W))=0$ for every bounded function $g:\mathbb{Z}^+\to \mathbb{R}$

$$\begin{align}
E[\lambda g(W+1)] &= \sum_{k\geq 0} \lambda g(k+1)\lambda^k\frac{e^{-\lambda}}{k!} \\
E[Wg(W)] &= \sum_{k\geq 0} k g(k)\lambda^k\frac{e^{-\lambda}}{k!} \\
\end{align}$$

But I don't know how to relate $g(k+1)$ to $g(k)$ so as to compare the sums?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's write $p_k = e^{-\lambda}\lambda^k/k!$ for $k\ge 0.$ Note that $$E(Wg(W))=\sum_{k\ge 0} k g(k) p_k = \sum_{k\ge 1} k g(k) p_k.$$ Now, we can substitute $k=l+1$ for the index. This will change the last sum to $$\sum_{l\ge 0} (l+1)g(l+1) p_{l+1}.$$ Observe that $$(l+1)p_{l+1} =(l+1)e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^{l+1}}{(l+1)!}=\lambda p_l.$$ Hence the sum becomes $$\sum_{l\ge 0} \lambda g(l+1) p_l$$ which is same as $E(\lambda g(W+1)).$

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
\begin{align*}
E(\lambda g(W+1)-Wg(W))
&=\sum_{k\geq 0} \lambda g(k+1)\lambda^k\frac{e^{-\lambda}}{k!}
-\sum_{k\geq 0} k g(k)\lambda^k\frac{e^{-\lambda}}{k!}\\
&=\sum_{k\geq 0} g(k+1)\lambda^{k+1}\frac{e^{-\lambda}(k+1)}{(k+1)!}
-\sum_{k\geq 0} k g(k)\lambda^k\frac{e^{-\lambda}}{k!}\\
&=\sum_{k\geq 1} g(k)\lambda^{k}\frac{e^{-\lambda}(k)}{(k)!}
-\sum_{k\geq 1} k g(k)\lambda^k\frac{e^{-\lambda}}{k!}\\
&=0.
\end{align*}